# Can you please unban my account?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, post-ban

I realized how I was asking questions was probably the wrong way to ask, and I wasn't contributing to the community much.  I've learned not to ask questions without thoroughly researching it first.

I don't know what else to say, except I'm sorry for not contributing to the community.  I will try harder to contribute more.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't appear to be currently blocked from asking questions, but be careful - you are right on that edge of having your account blocked again.

The voting on your content is a measurement of how much the community finds your content worthwhile, and most of your posts have been either down-voted or not voted on at all. The intention of a posting block is to ask that you work on your existing content before trying to post further.

Please read through the suggestions below so you do not run into similar problems in the future and for suggestions on what to do if you do:

- [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)
- [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Good luck!

Comment: Are you sure that you want to mark that "status-completed"? I know what you're getting at, but initially it gave me the wrong impression. "Want to be unbanned? Sure, here you go".

Comment: I'm agreeing with @Bart here, removing the status tag. I did a double take when I saw it too. Sending the wrong signal is one reason, we didn't actually 'do' anything is the other. Feel free to revert if you feel strongly otherwise, though.

Comment: I don't particularly care either way. :)